# Connecting multiple computers in one router ethernet port versus connecting multiple computers in multiple ethernet ports

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, gaming, lag

My local network has 3 computers connected to a single router ethernet port, through a switch. When one computer opens and in the other computer someone is already playing online games, the game lags for some initial time.

Would it make a difference if we connected each of the computers to different ethernet router ports (1 computer goes to 1 ethernet port only)?

Edited question: My network topology:

[image]

Comment: Possibly. You are currently sharing the bandwidth of one Ethernet connection connection into the switch between the 3 devices connected downstream of the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not - in fact, if this switch is capable of the same speed as the router ports and all devices connect to it it is likely beneficial as the switching in most  SOHO routers uses the CPU and bridging and this can seriously slow performance - something not typically an issue on a switch.

It's more likely likely the Internet connection is congested and that is the cause of the slowdown.

Note that if there are multiple active ports/paths between routers and switches and they are not configured correctly this can cause serious routing issues, since that may be worth checking as well.

Comment: I didn't think that a router can actually under perform when using multiple ports due to the way they manage them. The only thing that I did not add in the question is that one of the three computers connected to the switch is behind a power line connection. The other two are directly connected to the switch with ethernet cables. I updated the question with my network topology

Comment: The power line connection could limit the speed to/from devices connecting using it it won't affect other devices.